# Git/GitHub push to someone else's fork of my repo

Tags: git, github, permissions, push

I create a repository, which was then forked by one of my colleagues.
Working together yesterday we cloned **his** fork on my computer

```
git clone https://github.com/hisname/hisfork.git
```

and worked on a local branch tracking a non-master remote branch created by

```
git checkout -b localbranch origin/hisdevelopmentbranch
```

I tried to push these changes entering

```
git push origin localbranch:hisdevelopmentbranch
```

thinking that git would have ask for his username and password.
The error I get is

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 2.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (9/9), completed with 6 local objects.
To https://github.com/hisname/hisfork.git
 ! [remote rejected] localbranch -> hisdevelopmentbranch (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hisname/hisfork.git'
```

even after **he added me as a collaborator** to his fork.
I search for answers, but I can get the point. Usually I see something like ssh clone instead of url, configuration files, but I think it's something very easier!

**EDIT**

```
.....$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/hisname/hisfork.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/hisname/hisfork.git (push)
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: By this command `git push origin localbranch:hisdevelopmentbranch` you are trying to rename the branch?

Comment: No, `hisdevelopmentbranch` is the name of his remote branch. `localbranch` is the name of the local branch tracking it (obtained by `git checkout -b localbranch origin/hisdevelopmentbranch`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your own user is being used to authenticate to github.

You can either modify your git remote to specify your colleague's github user,
like so:

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://hisname@github.com/hisname/hisfork.git
```

OR

```
git remote set-url origin https://hisname@github.com/hisname/hisfork.git
```

OR

you can have your colleague add you as a "collaborator" to his fork of your repo, [Like so: Inviting collaborators on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).

EDIT:
As mentioned by OP in the comments, you also need to *accept the invitation* to collaborate before collaboration can take place (STEP #8 in the docs linked above).

Comment: I am a collaborator. He added me as collaborator after I cloned the repository.

Comment: I did `git remote set-url origin https://hisname@github.com/hisname/hisfork.git` and then `git push origin local branch:hisdevelopmentbranch`. I was asked the password, but I had to use his password, since mine doesn't work, even if **I am** a collaborator. Can you please help me to understand what's going on? (it's likely that I'm going to be in the same situation some other day.)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis when you changed the remote to `hisname@github.com` you effectively tell github to use his user account, not yours, which is what I thought your original question indicated you were expecting. Why your user isn't working despite being added as a collaborator, I'm not exactly sure. Can you confirm (i) When using the original remote, is it `yourname` that's being used for authentication? (ii) Do you happen to have any sort of keychain/password manager running in the background? (iii) You do infact have write/push permissions to his fork of your repo?

Comment: The problem is simply that I had to accept the invitation to collaborate. After that, the permissions are active. If you add this particular to your answer, I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Added that to the answer, it's already mentioned as part of the docs I linked to.